# How can I optimize this code further

Tags: java, algorithm

How can I optimize this piece of code further.
And if possible, please suggest what I should usually keep in mind.

```
public void funct(String str, int[] arr) {
        String temp = "saved";
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (str.equals(temp) && arr[i] * 2 > 10) {
                Integer num = new Integer(arr[i]);
                num = num * 2;
                System.out.print(num.toString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Thank You

Comment: This is more of a [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) question. If you want some help here, please state what is your intention, what should the method do, what is the usual input and what is the ecpected output. We do like code, but we don't like guessing. Apart from that, use `int num = arr[i];` instead of making a whole new `Integer` instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code doesn't make much sense as it stands, e.g. `str` and `temp` aren't really needed. So the first step in optimizing them is to remove them... Also use `int`, not `Integer`:

```
public void funct(int[] arr) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] > 5) {
                System.out.print(arr[i] * 2);
            }
        }
    }
```

And if you care about code conciseness:

```
public void funct(int[] arr) {
    for(int i: arr) {
        if (i > 5) {
            System.out.print(i * 2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, first multiplication in the condition is not really needed.

Comment: if (arr[i]>5) should be enough.

Answer (score 3):

Two observations:

1. Replace the boxed `Integer` object with an `int`.
2. You're doing the same `str.equals(temp)` check every time through the loop.  Why not do the entire loop inside `if(str.equals(temp))`?

Answer (score 0):

Note that on account of overflow, the expression `arr[i] * 2 > 10` is actually equivalent to `(arr[i] > 5 && arr[i] < 1073741824) || (arr[i] > -2147483643 && arr[i] < -1073741824)`, which is probably not what you wanted, but just in case, the suggested optimization to `arr[i] > 5` is not semantics-preserving.

Answer (score 0):

If you are really concerned about the String Comparison then your code can be written as below.

```
public void funct(String str, int[] arr)
{
    if (!str.equals("saved"))
        return; //just return if String value is not "saved", reduces the loop execution.
    for(int i: arr) {
        if (i>5)
            System.out.println(""+(i<<1)); //Left shift is faster than multiplication. Concatenation is just for printing as SOP will not print integers directly.
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.